# ActiveRecord query for coaches a client has bookmarked

Tags: performance, ruby, ruby-on-rails, comparative-review, active-record

I'm trying to figure out the best way to set up an ActiveRecord query.

---

### Models

There are three relevant models involved:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookmarks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :saved_coaches, through: :bookmarks, source: :bookmarkable, source_type: "Coach"
end

class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :bookmarkable, polymorphic: true

  scope :type, -> (type) { where(bookmarkable_type: type.to_s.capitalize) }
end

class Coach < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookmarks, as: :bookmarkable, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
end
```

---

### The problem

I need a performant query to access to the coaches a client has bookmarked, the coach's user model, and the id of relevant bookmark.

I can think of two approaches:

```
@client = current_user.client

# option 1
@coach_bookmarks = @client.bookmarks.type(:coach).includes(bookmarkable: :user)

# option 2
@coaches = Coach.includes(:bookmarks, :user)
  .where(bookmarks: { bookmarkable_type: "Coach", client: @client })
```

Option 1 seems clearer, but produces a collection of bookmarks, when most of the data I need is on the associated coach. Option 2 gives me a collection of coaches, but the query is a little less clear, and the SQL output is huge. (I've included that below.)

Is one of these solutions better than the other? Is there a third, better solution (maybe through `@client.saved_coaches`)?

---

### SQL output

Option 1

```
Bookmark Load (1.3ms)  SELECT "bookmarks".* FROM "bookmarks" WHERE "bookmarks"."client_id" = $1 AND "bookmarks"."bookmarkable_type" = $2  [["client_id", 3], ["bookmarkable_type", "Coach"]]
Coach Load (2.3ms)  SELECT "coaches".* FROM "coaches" WHERE "coaches"."id" IN (1)
User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" IN (3)
```

Option 2

```
SQL (6.3ms)  SELECT "coaches"."id" AS t0_r0, "coaches"."user_id" AS t0_r1,
"coaches"."questionnaire_submitted" AS t0_r2, "coaches"."validated" AS t0_r3,
"coaches"."verified" AS t0_r4, "coaches"."membership_type" AS t0_r5,
"coaches"."new_coach" AS t0_r6, "coaches"."created_at" AS t0_r7,
"coaches"."updated_at" AS t0_r8, "coaches"."title" AS t0_r9,
"coaches"."image_url" AS t0_r10, "coaches"."experience_years" AS t0_r11,
"coaches"."specialties" AS t0_r12, "coaches"."session_types" AS t0_r13,
"coaches"."session_type_other" AS t0_r14, "coaches"."meeting_types" AS t0_r15,
"coaches"."meeting_type_other" AS t0_r16, "coaches"."cancellation_policy" AS
t0_r17, "coaches"."bio" AS t0_r18, "coaches"."price_options" AS t0_r19,
"coaches"."quote" AS t0_r20, "coaches"."current_screen" AS t0_r21,
"coaches"."address_raw" AS t0_r22, "coaches"."business_phone" AS t0_r23,
"coaches"."address_city" AS t0_r24, "coaches"."address_state" AS t0_r25,
"coaches"."address_area" AS t0_r26, "coaches"."latitude" AS t0_r27,
"coaches"."longitude" AS t0_r28, "coaches"."categories" AS t0_r29,
"coaches"."keywords" AS t0_r30, "coaches"."ace_up_handles" AS t0_r31,
"coaches"."stripe_account_id" AS t0_r32, "coaches"."bank_account_info" AS
t0_r33, "coaches"."offer_free_consult" AS t0_r34,
"coaches"."free_consult_length" AS t0_r35, "coaches"."sessions_start_every" AS
t0_r36, "coaches"."max_daily_sessions" AS t0_r37,
"coaches"."minimum_scheduling_notice" AS t0_r38,
"coaches"."buffer_after_session" AS t0_r39, "coaches"."num_reviews" AS t0_r40,
"coaches"."onboard_professional_background" AS t0_r41,
"coaches"."onboard_certifications" AS t0_r42, "coaches"."onboard_challenges"
AS t0_r43, "coaches"."onboard_promoting" AS t0_r44,
"coaches"."onboard_referral_source" AS t0_r45, "coaches"."onboard_interests"
AS t0_r46, "coaches"."onboard_submitted" AS t0_r47, "coaches"."coach_url" AS
t0_r48, "coaches"."timezone" AS t0_r49, "coaches"."average_review" AS t0_r50,
"coaches"."coach_order" AS t0_r51, "coaches"."onboard_business" AS t0_r52,
"coaches"."onboard_services" AS t0_r53, "coaches"."videos" AS t0_r54,
"coaches"."card_highlights" AS t0_r55, "coaches"."edit_requested" AS t0_r56,
"coaches"."specialties_edit" AS t0_r57, "coaches"."session_types_edit" AS
t0_r58, "coaches"."meeting_types_edit" AS t0_r59,
"coaches"."cancellation_policy_edit" AS t0_r60, "coaches"."bio_edit" AS
t0_r61, "coaches"."quote_edit" AS t0_r62, "coaches"."keywords_career" AS
t0_r63, "coaches"."keywords_life" AS t0_r64, "coaches"."keywords_leadership"
AS t0_r65, "coaches"."keywords_business" AS t0_r66,
"coaches"."keywords_communication" AS t0_r67, "coaches"."keywords_executive"
AS t0_r68, "coaches"."qualifications" AS t0_r69, "coaches"."education" AS
t0_r70, "coaches"."target_clients" AS t0_r71, "coaches"."highlights" AS
t0_r72, "coaches"."client_review_link" AS t0_r73, "coaches"."consent" AS
t0_r74, "coaches"."qualifications_edit" AS t0_r75, "coaches"."education_edit"
AS t0_r76, "coaches"."target_clients_edit" AS t0_r77,
"coaches"."highlights_edit" AS t0_r78, "coaches"."text_notifications" AS
t0_r79, "coaches"."email_notifications" AS t0_r80, "coaches"."companies" AS
t0_r81, "coaches"."address_raw_edit" AS t0_r82, "coaches"."longitude_edit" AS
t0_r83, "coaches"."latitude_edit" AS t0_r84, "bookmarks"."id" AS t1_r0,
"bookmarks"."client_id" AS t1_r1, "bookmarks"."bookmarkable_id" AS t1_r2,
"bookmarks"."bookmarkable_type" AS t1_r3, "users"."id" AS t2_r0,
"users"."email" AS t2_r1, "users"."encrypted_password" AS t2_r2,
"users"."reset_password_token" AS t2_r3, "users"."reset_password_sent_at" AS
t2_r4, "users"."remember_created_at" AS t2_r5, "users"."sign_in_count" AS
t2_r6, "users"."current_sign_in_at" AS t2_r7, "users"."last_sign_in_at" AS
t2_r8, "users"."current_sign_in_ip" AS t2_r9, "users"."last_sign_in_ip" AS
t2_r10, "users"."confirmation_token" AS t2_r11, "users"."confirmed_at" AS
t2_r12, "users"."confirmation_sent_at" AS t2_r13, "users"."unconfirmed_email"
AS t2_r14, "users"."failed_attempts" AS t2_r15, "users"."unlock_token" AS
t2_r16, "users"."locked_at" AS t2_r17, "users"."encrypted_otp_secret" AS
t2_r18, "users"."encrypted_otp_secret_iv" AS t2_r19,
"users"."encrypted_otp_secret_salt" AS t2_r20, "users"."consumed_timestep" AS
t2_r21, "users"."otp_required_for_login" AS t2_r22, "users"."personal_phone"
AS t2_r23, "users"."name" AS t2_r24, "users"."created_at" AS t2_r25,
"users"."updated_at" AS t2_r26, "users"."google_token" AS t2_r27,
"users"."google_refresh_token" AS t2_r28, "users"."last_calendar_refresh" AS
t2_r29, "users"."google_expires_at" AS t2_r30,
"users"."google_calendar_refresh_tokens" AS t2_r31, "users"."acquisition" AS
t2_r32, "users"."icalendar_urls" AS t2_r33, "users"."admin" AS t2_r34,
"users"."banned" AS t2_r35, "users"."email_subscriber" AS t2_r36,
"users"."intermediate_reminder_sent" AS t2_r37, "users"."final_reminder_sent"
AS t2_r38 FROM "coaches" LEFT OUTER JOIN "bookmarks" ON
"bookmarks"."bookmarkable_id" = "coaches"."id" AND
"bookmarks"."bookmarkable_type" = $1 LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" =
"coaches"."user_id" WHERE "bookmarks"."bookmarkable_type" = $2 AND
"bookmarks"."client_id" = 3  [["bookmarkable_type", "Coach"],
["bookmarkable_type", "Coach"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

if you don't need the bookmarks instances then I would be inclined to go for something like:

```
@coaches = Coach
             .joins(:bookmarks).includes(:user)
             .where(bookmarks: { bookmarkable_type: "Coach", client: @client })
```

though I would wrap that in a scope. You could probably also get away with excluding the `bookmarkable_type: "Coach"` condition since the join will enforce that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need their IDs. I didn't realize I could drop the "bookmarkable_type," though, and wrapping it into a scope was a good idea. I created a `Bookmarkable` concern to hold the `has_many :bookmarks` association and a new `bookmarked_by` scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
@coaches = Coach
             .includes(:user)
             .joins(:bookmarks)
             .where(bookmarks: { bookmarkable_type: "Coach", client: @client })
             .select("coaches.*, bookmarks.id AS bookmark_id")
```

After this query you can do the following:

```
@coaches.first.id # returns coach id
@coaches.first.bookmark_id # returns the relevant bookmark_id
@coaches.first.user.name # returns the user's name of that coach.
```

This approach has one advantage over including the collection of bookmarks that it won't load the whole objects of bookmarks into memory when you need only bookmark_id.